# How to focusing map to user location?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I created a `MapActivity` that will be focusing the map to user location.

```
public void getMyLatLng() {
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener ll = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            myLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
        }
    };
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
    lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    //myLatLng = new LatLng(myLoc.getLatitude(), myLoc.getLongitude());
}
```

I got `java.lang.NullPointerException` issue when it is run for first time.
But when I run it again, it works.
And the second issue is, it'll work well when I put NETWORK_PROVIDER instead GPS_PROVIDER.
Any advice to solve this issue?

Comment: Please provide logat output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request location updates from both GPS and nework
Something like this:

```
 public class LocationService implements LocationListener {

    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    final static long MIN_TIME_INTERVAL = 60 * 1000L;

    Location location;


    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; // 10

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1; // 1 minute

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    private CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(5 * 1000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            stopUsingGPS();
        }
    };

    public LocationService() {
        super(R.id.gps_service_id);
    }


    public void start() {
        if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {

            try {


                timer.start();


                locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        Location tempLocation = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (tempLocation != null
                                && isBetterLocation(tempLocation,
                                        location))
                            location = tempLocation;
                    }
                }
                if (isGPSEnabled) {

                    locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, this, null);
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        Location tempLocation = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (tempLocation != null
                                && isBetterLocation(tempLocation,
                                        location))
                            location = tempLocation;
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                onTaskError(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            onOfflineResponse(requestData);
        }
    }

    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(LocationService.this);
        }
    }

    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        return isGPSEnabled || isNetworkEnabled;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (location != null
                && isBetterLocation(location, this.location)) {

            this.location = location;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public Object getResponseObject(Object location) {
        return location;
    }

    public static boolean isBetterLocation(Location location,
            Location currentBestLocation) {
        if (currentBestLocation == null) {
            // A new location is always better than no location
            return true;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
        long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
        boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > MIN_TIME_INTERVAL;
        boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -MIN_TIME_INTERVAL;
        boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

        // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location,
        // use the new location
        // because the user has likely moved
        if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
            return true;
            // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must
            // be worse
        } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
        int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation
                .getAccuracy());
        boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
        boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
        boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

        // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
        boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
                currentBestLocation.getProvider());

        // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and
        // accuracy
        if (isMoreAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate
                && isFromSameProvider) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Notice that every time we get a location we are comparing it with already known location to find of this new location is better by calling isBetterLocation.

Answer (score 0):

To receive location form GPS satellite, need some times.

If your testing location was indoor, GPS signal is too week so you may couldn't get locaion.

Instead of using network provider, you can receive location when you were in buildings, but it has low accuracy than GPS.

Answer (score 0):

if you use the google map api 2 on android you could implements the [LocationSource](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/LocationSource.html) to force the map to a location where you want.